# Why is "had" followed by a past participle while "had to" followed by an infinitive?

Tags: infinitives, past-participles, parts-of-speech

"Had" is an auxiliary verb, right? In which case it should be followed by an infinitive. Why is it followed by a past participle in that case? Am I mistaken?

Example "she had paid" vs "she had to pay".

Comment: Auxiliary verbs are followed by non-finite forms.  Non-finite forms can be either infinitives or participles. *Have* is an auxiliary in *have paid*, and *be* is an auxiliary in *be paid* or *be paying*.

Comment: There is the idiom: **to have to do something**, have is **not an auxiliary" +  there is an auxiliary where **had is the past perfect**: had paid, had seen.

Answer (score 3):

"had to" is the past equivalent of the present tense "have to" which means  *necessary*. Its meaning and usage is very similar to “[must](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/must)”, a modal verb which does not add an "s" in the 3rd person singular and is not used to express a completed action in the past.

- We **have to** go out and vote now. = We *must* go out and vote
- We **had to** go out and vote yesterday. = It *was necessary* that we go out
- She **has to** pay the speeding ticket.  = She *must* pay…
- She **had to** pay the speeding ticket.  = It *was necessary* that she pay…

The construction with “had” as an *auxiliary* is used for the [Past Perfect](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-past-perfect-tense). The [Present Perfect](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-present-perfect-tense) and the Past Perfect are formed using either the present or the past tense of the verb ***have* + the past participle** of the main verb.

The third person singular

- She **has paid** the speeding ticket. (Present Perfect)
- She **had paid** the speeding ticket. (Past Perfect)

---

The first person plural

- We'**ve seen** wild deer in these parts.
- We **had seen** wild deer in these parts.

Comment: It's worth pointing out the idiom: to have to do something.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *She had paid the bill*.
>
> [2] *She had to pay the bill*.

"Have" is always an auxiliary when it marks the perfect tense, where it normally occurs with a following past participle, as in [1].

But when it occurs in clauses describing states, expressing such meaning as  possession (*She has enough money*)  or obligation, as in your example [2], usage is divided. Most speakers treat it as a lexical verb, but some treat it as an auxiliary verb, compare:

[3] *Did she have to pay the bill*? [lexical "have"]

[4] *Had she to pay the bill*?  [auxiliary "have"]

Both [3] and [4] are questions that require subject-auxiliary inversion. But in [3] there is no auxiliary verb present, so the dummy auxiliary verb "do" is inserted, just as it would be with any other lexical verb, e.g. *He ate all the pie ~ Did he eat all the pie?*

But [4], by contrast, does not require the insertion of dummy "do". Instead, to form a question we simply invert the subject "she" and the verb "had" , thus proving that "had" is here an auxiliary verb.